# Accessing a property in a LINQ WHERE statement by name

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Just wondering whether this is possible. I have various LINQ queries against an Entity Framework context, like:

```
 IQueryable<MetaData> metaDataList = context.MetaData.AsQueryable();
 metaDataList = metaDataList.Where(md => md.MetaTagFilter1.Equals(keyValueMetaTagFilter.MetaTagValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
 metaDataList = metaDataList.Where(md => md.MetaTagFilter2.Equals(keyValueMetaTagFilter.MetaTagValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
 metaDataList = metaDataList.Where(md => md.MetaTagFilter3.Equals(keyValueMetaTagFilter.MetaTagValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

As you see, they are identical except for the property being used: MetaTagFilter1, MetaTagFilter2, MetaTagFilter3.

Instead of repeating this over and over, I would like to write a method 'Filter' so that I can call it like:

```
metaDataList = metaDataList.Filter("MetaTagFilter1");  
metaDataList = metaDataList.Filter("MetaTagFilter2"); 
metaDataList = metaDataList.Filter("MetaTagFilter3");
```

So property name is passed as a string, and this property should then be used in the LINQ query.

I tried by passing the property as a Func and by reflection, but LINQ to entities cannot translate those statements if used in a LINQ query.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: What about Dynamic LINQ? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinqKit. It allows you to use methods in your query as long as they return expression trees.

So create an expression in the method based on a parameter which describes which property to use.

See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx